# How to give Vertical Spacing between each TableRow in Flutter Table

Tags: flutter, tablerow

Right now I am adding TableRow with two empty Text as shown below. But I don't think this is a Solution. There might be something I am missing.

```
Table(
    children:[
    TableRow(
    children: [
    Text('Investment needed'),
    Text(proposalDetailsData.maxInvestment) ]),

 TableRow(
    children: [
    Text(''),
    Text('')
    ]),
    ]);

    TableRow(
    children: [
    Text('Minimum Investment'),
    Text(proposalDetailsData.investmentRaised)
    ]),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since each `Activity` has its own `ViewModelStore` and every `ViewModelStore` creates a different instance of a `ViewModel`. You could only do that by using a  `ViewModelFactory` which acts as a singleton factory, that is in its `create` method would always return the same object.

I would definitely avoid that, and wouldn't go against the framework, and choose one of the below options:

**1)** To save, retain data across VM's you could use a **Singleton Repository**, or **Data Source**

**2)** If you insist in one single `VM` you could use one activity, one ViewModel with three fragments. (IMO this is the best option)

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept. I will try the 2nd option.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been raised before in the google samples repo: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29

One potential solution provided in that thread is https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29#issuecomment-351620004

Ideally, if you use one main activity and just use fragments for everything else, it is much easier to share the same instance of a ViewModel.

Hopefully, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent for send value from activity A to activity B.

Comment: Please read the question properly before answering the question. I don't want to send value between or from Activities. I want to initialize my User model value using same viewmodel in activities which has edit text to get user data using mvvm approach.